# HTML image attribute returns undefined

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, cloudinary

I have a set of 5 images each with a unique filter attribute in a list of filters and the main image in a separate div.
The main image does not have a filter applied to it.

I would like to have users click on any of the images on the sidebar and then apply the selected filter to the main image.
I tried using an event listener for that but I don't really understand what's happening.

Here's my code:
`<img src='http://res.cloudinary.com/demo/image/upload/c_fill,e_art:audrey,h_80,w_120/sample' filter='audrey' className='filter' />`
and an event listener that gets called when a user selects an image.

```
onFilterSelect = event => {
      console.log(evenet.target) // returnsimg element
      console.log(event.target.src) // returns src of img element
      console.log(event.target.filter) // returns undefined
}
```

I would like to use the `filter='filter'` prop to dispatch an action that sets the state to the newly selected filter but I keep on getting undefined as a result.

Comment: don't think it has anything to do with react, filter is not a valid property for `img` isn't it ? Did you try with `data-attribute` ? `<img src='http://res.cloudinary.com/demo/image/upload/c_fill,e_art:audrey,h_80,w_120/sample' data-filter='audrey' className='filter' />` then `console.log(event.target.attributes['filter'].value)` in your handler

Comment: If custom attributes are being used, @Olivier, then: `event.target.dataset.filter` would return the attribute-string.

Comment: thanks, yes I forgot about the `dataset` property

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`HTMLImageElement.prototype` does not have a `filter` **property** (which you are trying to access).

**Your** image has a `filter`-**attribute** (which makes your HTML invalid because it is not a valid attribute on `img` elements).

If you need to stick with that invalid attribute name, you can access it using

```
console.log(event.target.getAttribute('filter'))
```

The better solution would be to change that attribute to a `data-filter` attribute, which you can access like this:

```
console.log(event.target.dataset.filter)
```

Please note that there is a special naming convention in the `.dataset` object:

```
data-filter="Audrey"
```

can be accessed using

```
img.dataset.filter
```

but

```
data-image-filter="Audrey"
```

would be accessed using

```
img.dataset.imageFilter
```

Notice the automatic conversion of kebab-case to camel-case!

Comment: I didn't realize I was using an invalid attribute name. Thank you, it worked!

Comment: You can create new attributes on any HTML element, as long as a) the attribute name starts with `data-`, b) contains only lower-case letters and dashes, c) does not have a dash at the end, d) does not have more than one dash in succession.

Comment: Please don't forget to mark the answer as correct answer solving your problem.

Comment: I can't believe I forgot that, thanks for the reminder. Your answer really helped me.

Comment: So why did you pick the much less exhaustive answer. Are you sure it's the best answer with regard to explaining what's wrong and how to fix it?

Comment: It was just a tiny mistake. Pardon me but I'm actually kind of a newbie here.

Comment: No problem, just asking to make sure you did what you wanted to do.

Comment: Now no answer is picked again, making future readers think that your question isn't answered yet.

Answer (score 1):

```
console.log(event.target.getAttribute('filter'))
```

Not all HTML attributes are in element's properties. Also using `data` is better for custom attributes, as suggested by others.